# How to auto indent after curly braces in tkinter textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

How to implement this formatting in tkinter textbox?

I want to get the text in the textbox like this:

```
{
    {
        { (enter key pressed after this left brace)
            text 1
            
        } (enter key pressed after this right brace)
        text 2
    }
}
```

After writing some text after text 2 if I wish to write some more text after text 1 then I want to get the same indentation that of text 1. How to do this?

Comment: You would have to create a collection of the users previous 2 or more keystrokes and if those key strokes include a `{` and `ENTER` emit a signal that would automatically create some measure of indentation.

Comment: I implemented this but I cannot do the second part of the question.

Comment: for the second part you will want to check the user keystrokes and if the last keystroke was a `}`  you will need to emit a signal that analyzes the where the cursor is currently located and checks to see where the opening brack is located and calculate the measure of indent less than the previous measure.